# How to click the nearest anchor when my custom checkbox is toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Faceted search with Custom Checkbox]

HTML

```
<li class="leaf">

  // The span is my custom checkbox that wraps around the default checkbox.     
  <span class="checkbox facetapi-checkbox checked">

    // The span above replaces the default checkbox below, which you'll notice has a display:none; I don't want both checkboxes showing.
    <input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox" checked="true" style="display: none; ">

  </span>


  // This is the anchor tag that I need to click when my custom checkbox is checked.
  // It's outside of my custom checkbox span, but shares the same parent.  
  <a href="/part-finder/field_rep_catalog/heater-1527" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-active facetapi-checkbox-processed" style="display: none; ">(-) 
     <span class="element-invisible">Remove Support filter</span>
  </a>

</li>
```

Here is the jQuery used to replace the default checkbox with my custom one:

```
//Checkbox Image Replacement 
$('.faceted_search_column input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
  var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    span.addClass('checked');
  }
  $(this).wrap(span).hide();
});

// You'll notice that when this function is run, I've attempted to use .closest() to find the nearest anchor and then do a .triggerHandler('click') to click that anchor it finds. This obviously didn't work. Should I use .parent() to move back in the DOM?
function doCheck() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
    // This was my attempt to click the anchor when doCheck function is run.
    $(this).closest('a.facetapi-checkbox-processed').triggerHandler('click');
    $(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    $(this).parents('a.facetapi-checkbox-processed').triggerHandler('click');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
    $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
  }
}

function doDown() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
}

function doUp() {
  $(this).removeClass('clicked');
}
```

What do you guys recommend as the most efficient way to trigger that anchor click when the user toggles the checkbox? It's a faceted search anchor, so I need both checked or unchecked to trigger the same anchor tag.

Thanks in advance for those who take the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest only looks at an elements direct ancestors. you can use a combination of closest('li') and find('a') to accomplish your goal.

```
 $(this).closest('li').find('a.facetapi-checkbox-processed').click();
```

TriggerHandler does not bubble up the dom tree, so its trying to trigger the click on the Anchor only, which there is no trigger bound to the Anchor tag. Use trigger('click') or simply .click() to have the event propagate up to your event handler on the span, or change the find to look directly for the span.

Comment: This didn't work. I also tried to just use the .find('a') to see if that would work, but no luck :(

Comment: @HoldTheLine See update, is the find('a') returning nothing, or does the click not do anything?

Comment: You are the man! Thanks a lot for your informative response. Although I was unable to be successful with your supplied answer, you put me on the right path. I was able to achieve a solution with $(this).closest('li').find('a').attr('href'); Thank you very much Rob!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your following line:

```
$(this).closest('a.facetapi-checkbox-processed').triggerHandler('click');
```

for this one:

```
$(this).siblings('a.facetapi-checkbox-processed').triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: I was under the impression that sibling had to be in the same parent element as the selector. So the input[type=checkbox] is nested inside of my jquery created <span class="checkbox facetapi-checkbox checked"></span>. I'm guessing that sibling would work if my anchor tag was also nested inside of the same span element?